# ERRO[0044] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm using Windows 10 Home and I got this error when connecting to docker:

```
ERRO[0044] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial tcp 192.168.99.101:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
context canceled
```

Can anybody help? I have seen solutions for Linux and OS, but not for windows

Comment: Unfortunately I experience the same on Gitlab CI.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue as well. Can you help?

Comment: No, sorry I did not

Answer (score 0):

I also use Window 10 Home edition,
On windows, run cmd in adminstrator mode
and run the folowing lines of code

```
docker-machine start
docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd > e:\servers\docker\setenv.bat
call e:\servers\docker\setenv.bat
del e:\servers\docker\setenv.bat
```

Continue in the same CMD instance to run your docker client commands
Dont forget to change docker folder path based on your environments.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer from [ERRO[0043] failed to dial gRPC: unable to upgrade to h2c, received 501](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731184/erro0043-failed-to-dial-grpc-unable-to-upgrade-to-h2c-received-501/58731185):

Following one of the comments in https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/71, I enabled Experimental features in Settings->Daemon and the problem went away. I have no idea how or why it fixed it and another commenter there says they fixed it by disabling Experimental features.

[image]