# ERRO[0043] failed to dial gRPC: unable to upgrade to h2c, received 501

Tags: docker

When I tried building my Dockerfile with `docker build -t myimage1 .` today I got this error:

```
ERRO[0043] failed to dial gRPC: unable to upgrade to h2c, received 501
context canceled
```

I have successfully built this image before although it was a couple of weeks ago. I am not sure whether Docker has been updated in the meantime.

I found a similar error (although not the same - it is error 0044 while mine is 0043) at [ERRO[0044] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308947/erro0044-failed-to-dial-grpc-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon/58731161#58731161)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just started Docker daemon, please wait for some time and try again.

Answer (score -3):

You can uninstall and re install Docker, in Windows Platform, to remove the Docker Error. also, if you have not upgraded Docker version, you can do that too, it should remove the error.